# Textacy has no module preprocess or normalize whitespace

Tags: python, spacy, textacy

Sudden problems with textacy

```
text3 = textacy.normalize_whitespace(text2)
```

AttributeError: module 'textacy' has no attribute 'normalize_whitespace'

This happens in Python 3.7

The script worked perfectly for the past year. The other day this error started happening. I feel I've tried everything. The line is critical to the program.

I created a python 3.6 env and an earlier version of textacy. Can't import textacy there because it says I don't have cachetools - I do.

Is there an approach you can recommend?

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik None I can find anywhere. I didn't name any files textacy.py.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm out of ideas then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is located at `textacy.preprocessing`, cf [here](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy/blob/master/textacy/preprocessing/normalize.py) and [here](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy/blob/master/textacy/preprocessing/__init__.py), so you'll have to change the code to:

```
from textacy import preprocessing
text3 = preprocessing.normalize_whitespace(text2)
```

Comment: You are correct - I've tried that also but it does not work. I went back to versions from last year even, prior textacy, conda and spacy and still...how could it have worked before and not now? This seems crazy.

Comment: I just tried a clean install of `textacy` in a new environment. I edited my original answer, the code above should work now.